# How to use Android modem without using PC

Tags: root-access, command-line, gsm

I have rooted my mobile. I wanted to use modem of Android phone without connecting to PC. How to give AT commands without connecting to PC, because in http://atinout.sourceforge.net/, it is suggesting to use `'/dev/ttyACM0'` file which is not present in Android device. 
I am not sure, but it seems `ttyACM0` is related with USB, how to use same command in Android mobile, if I have rooted my mobile successfully.

Comment: Have you checked if kernel's Android USB gadget support does include *ACM serial support*, *generic serial function driver* and finally *modem support in generic serial function driver*?

Comment: @t0mm13b Can you please suggest how to check this? I am new to Linux world.

Comment: Did anybody ever "stepped by stepped" detailed how you could solve this issue ? ... I'm tryna do the same thing (or possibly embed it in my Java apk...)

Answer (score 2):

Some devices would have the kernel compiled with ACM serial support (*this is dependent on manufacturer/board/kernel*) so that it could be used as a dial-up modem from a PC via USB cable, that is the functionality behind `/dev/ttyACM` **n** where **n** is a digit as allocated by the kernel.

To check for that, look in `/proc/config.gz` which is the kernel configuration file used, this is a gzipped file detailing the configuration of how the kernel was built, the ones you are looking for is, need to search for it:

- CONFIG_USB_ANDROID_ACM=y
- CONFIG_USB_F_SERIAL=y
- CONFIG_MODEM_SUPPORT=y

*again, its dependent, some elect to not include it, others will omit it*

So basing my comment above, I think you're using the wrong device file name, the real modem device file is `/dev/smd0` which is used in conjunction with `/dev/socket/rild` (See my answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11111953/206367) explaining about that). 
`/dev/smd0` sits in front of `/dev/socket/rild`, `rild` daemon reads from that device and relays it to `/dev/socket/rild` which is then handled by the android layer in both directions.

Try using either of the device filenames, with `atinout` program referenced on sourceforge, to see what outcome you will get.

**Disclaimer:** I am not responsible for messing up your telephony stuff if you carry it out as per on the sourceforge site, if it gets messed, reboot!

Answer (score 1):

As I said in [my answer to your first question](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/50820/12442):

> Be warned that the device file you need to use is different for each model of phone, so you'll have to examine /dev on each device to find out which file to use.

If you can't find a report from someone else who has got it working on the same phone, you'll need to use a little trial and error to find the right device file.